# After creating relying party trust in ADFS, how to validate configuration is correct using SAML tracer

Tags: logging, adfs, saml

I created a relying party trust in ADFS.

To test, I log into IDP, initiate link, select the relying party, enter  credentials, then the application page will display.

How do I perform this validation from the ADFS end using SAML tracer?